# Determining the class of a method

Tags: python

Let's say I have:

```
class User():
  def method(self):
    pass

u=User()
```

How do I extract the class from `u.method` through the `access` decorator?  All I get from `u.method` is that it is a function... but I'd like to know from which `class`.

I am interested in a python 2.7 solution.

**Update**: I forget to mention I didn't give enough details:

```
class access():
    """
    Decorator for specifying which 'access right' must be enforced 
    at the object method level  
    """

    def __init__(self, right):
        self.right=right

    def __call__(self, method):
      ### need to grab the method's class name here
```

I am actually using a decorator:

```
class User():
  @access("edit"
  def method(self):
    pass
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a classic class instead of a new-style class? (And, if you want a classic class, why do `User()` instead of just `User`?) It doesn't affect the answer in this case, but pretty much anywhere it _does_ make a difference, the classic class is not what you want.

Comment: Meanwhile, `u.method` is _not_ a function, it's a bound method. If you're seeing anything else, you're not running the same code you showed us. And, since functions don't have classes, your question is meaningless.

Comment: OK, after the edit… That's a completely different question. The decorator doesn't get the bound method `u.method`, or even the unbound method `U.method`, because `U.method` can't be created until after the decorator returns. It just gets a plain old function. So you can't inspect it for the class.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll probably need to revisit my approach then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decorator isn't being called with a method, it's being called with a function.

The class doesn't exist yet, and neither does the unbound method that ties the function to the class, much less any instance of the class and the bound method that ties the function to that instance. And, even when those methods *do* exist, they'll be built around the function your decorator returns.

So, you can't introspect the function you receive to try to get its class, because it doesn't have one.

---

There are various hacky tricks you can use to determine what you're in the middle of defining (although they may be specific to a particular Python implementation and version), but there's no clean way to do what you want. For example, here's one terrible hack:

```
self.classname = sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name
```

What does this mean? Well, your decorator itself is frame 0; whatever called it is frame 1. If the thing that called it is a class definition, its `code` object will have the class's name as its class. You still can't actually access the class yet, because it doesn't exist (and won't until the code is executed, which is in the middle of happening right now). But if you know the name will never be overridden, you can just store the name and look it up later (you also probably want `f_locals['__module__']` to look it up in) at call time, to get the class.

---

However, a much nicer solution is to create a class decorator and a method decorator that works with it. The trick is that the method decorators "register" in some way that they want (the functions they return) to be "fixed up". Then, the class decorator iterates through the registered methods and fixes them up.

For example:

```
def class_deco(cls):
    for name, method in inspect.getmembers(cls, callable):
        if hasattr(method, 'class_fixup'):
            method.class_fixup(cls)
    return cls
```

Now, your method decorator still can't access the class at call time, but it can create a "fixup" function that finishes decorating things when the class is ready, then just do `f.class_fixup = fixup` right before `return f`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `u.method.im_class`:

```
In [3]: u.method.im_class
Out[3]: __main__.User
```

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy)

> *User-defined methods*
>   ...
>   Special read-only attributes: `im_self` is the class instance object, `im_func` is the function object; `im_class` is the class of im_self for bound methods or the class that asked for the method for unbound methods.

In python 3, look up the class through `__self__`:

```
>>> u.method.__self__.__class__
<class '__main__.User'>
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'im_class'

Comment: @PavelAnossov: No, that just gives you `builtins.method`! Python 3 doesn't have an equivalent of `im_class` (because it's only needed for unbound methods, which no longer exist). You want `__self__.__class__`.

Comment: Oops, I mean `u.method.__self__.__class__`

Comment: I am interested in Python 2.7.x

Comment: @jldupont: In 2.7, `im_class` is correct. If you try it with exactly the code you put in your question, it works. The fact that the error message says "'function' object" instead of 'method' implies that you're not actually trying it with the same code. A _function_ doesn't _have_ a class.

Answer (score 0):

why not just print it?

```
class User():
  def method(self):
    pass

u=User()

print(u.method)
```

Output:

```
<bound method User.method of <__main__.User object at 0x02D59510>>
```

Or if you want to test you can use:

```
u.method.__self__.__class__
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.User'>
```

Both methods confirmed working in python `2.7.3` and python `3.3`

Comment: IIRC, `u.__method__.__self__` is not documented to work in 2.7. It happens to work in CPython 2.7.x for normally-created bound methods, but it may not work for bound methods created in other ways (or, of course, custom objects that simulate bound methods), and it may not work in other implementations (PyPy, Jython, IronPython, …). So you're probably better off using `u.method.im_class`, or at least `u.method.im_self.__class__`.

Comment: @abarnert I have a fresh install of 2.7.3 and this works with no errors. Though I think I see what you're getting at.

Comment: Serdalis: Yes, as I said, it happens to work in CPython 2.7.x for normally-created bound methods. So, if you make a fresh install of CPython 2.7.3, and create a bound method in the normal way, of course it will work.

Comment: Python is just a language specification. CPython is the reference implementation. If you don't know what Python you have, CPython is the one you have.

Comment: @abarnert you're saying that since it's not documented to work in 2.7 that it cannot be expected to work in all implementations of python 2.7?

Comment: Basically, yeah. (Of course you could test PyPy, IronPython, and Jython, and assume if anyone starts a new Python implementation tomorrow it'll probably be for 3.x instead of 2.7, which might be good enough. But I think it's safer to just use different 2.x and 3.x code here.)